# Trying to automatically open a document that is created by a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a spreadsheet that keeps track of a series of documents. Inside the spreadsheet I have a button which, upon being pressed, locates a particular template file from my drive and makes a copy of it. That script looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById("<template doc id goes here>");
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<folder where new file will go>"); 
    var newfile = "<newly created file name goes here>";

    file.makeCopy(newfile, folder);
}
```

Is there a way I can force the newly created document to open in a new tab once it is created? This way once the new doc is created, I do not need to navigate back to the folder and open in manually for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML Service for the original button, you can simply add a `window.open` function.

```
<script>
  function openTheUrl() {
    window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
  };
</script>
```

The URL to the new document can be returned with the `getUrl()` method of the File Class:

[Google Documentation - getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl())

There are multiple steps to this process.

- Call Apps Script `gs` function with `google.script.run` in HTML
- Google server side code creates the new document and returns a value
- The onSuccess callback function opens the new document

HTML Script tag to call apps script code, and define the success function:

```
<script>

  window.callServerCode = function() { 
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(openTheUrl)
    .myFunction();
  }

  function openTheUrl(argNewUrl) {
    Logger.log('argNewUrl: ' + argNewUrl);
    window.open(argNewUrl);
  };
</script>
```

The Apps Script code needs to return a value:

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("<template doc id goes here>");
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("<folder where new file will go>"); 
  var newfile = "<newly created file name goes here>";

  var newFile = file.makeCopy(newfile, folder);
  var newDocURL = newFile.getUrl();

  return newDocURL;
}
```

The `google.script.run` withSuccessHandler function automatically receives the return value.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this question [How to open a URL link from JavaScript inside a Google Apps Script HTML Google Site Gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737682/how-to-open-a-url-link-from-javascript-inside-a-google-apps-script-html-google-s) calling window.open won't work because of caja sanitization.

however you can add the url to a cel, or create a link in the HTML. The user will have to click on it to open the new sheet which may be not the solution you wanted, but it would save the time to look into drive for that new file.